# Turn an array of objects into an object of arrays with jq

Tags: json, jq

I would like to use `jq` to turn an array of objects into an object of arrays.

Consider if I have the following two files:

**file1.json**:

```
{
  "key1": 5,
  "key2": 10
}
```

**file2.json**:

```
{
  "key1": 2
}
```

I would like to merge them together to form:

```
{
  "key1": [5, 2]
  "key2": [10, null]
}
```

It's easy to do this with one field per `jq` command, but I can't figure out how to do it with all the fields at once.  My thought is that I need to convert all the values to arrays and then use reduce with `*`, but I couldn't get it to work.

The `jq` command needs to work for an arbitrary number of files (more than 2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will merge an array of objects into a single object as you describe (in particular, null is used as a filler, which certainly makes sense if, for example, each input object is regarded as an "observation"), but please note that merge/0 as defined here makes no assumptions about the sets of keys in the input objects, and could potentially be made much faster depending on the assumptions that could be made.

```
def merge:
  def allkeys: map(keys) | add | unique;
  allkeys as $allkeys
  | reduce .[] as $in ({};
     reduce $allkeys[] as $k (.;
       . + {($k): (.[$k] + [$in[$k]]) } ));

merge
```

Now use the "slurp" option, e.g.:

```
 $ jq -s -f merge.jq file*.json
```

Comment: How would you get this to work with an arbitrary number of files?

Comment: @schmmd -- Please note that the original version of merge/0 was not sufficiently general.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably slower than @peak's solution, but maybe easier to read:

```
map(to_entries)
| flatten(1)
| group_by(.key)
| map({
    key: .[0].key,
    value: map(.value)})
| from_entries
```

Use it like:

```
jq -s 'map(to_entries) | flatten(1) | group_by(.key) | map({key: .[0].key, value: map(.value)}) | from_entries' file*.json
```

Unlike your desired output, it does not put nulls in place of missing values, which may be useful if "null" is a valid value in itself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution.

```
  (add | keys) as $all                                                  # get all keys
| map( . as $o | reduce $all[] as $k ({}; .[$k] = $o[$k]) )             # normalize objects
|    ( . as $a | reduce $all[] as $k ({}; .[$k] = ($a | map(.[$k]))) )  # transpose
```

To run it use the `-s` option, e.g:

```
$ jq -s -f filter.jq file1.json file2.json
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "key1": [
    5,
    2
  ],
  "key2": [
    10,
    null
  ]
}
```

If you have more files, e.g. `file3.json`

```
{
  "key3": 2
}
```

just add them to the command line

```
$ jq -s -f filter.jq file1.json file2.json file3.json
```

Sample output:

```
{
  "key1": [
    5,
    2,
    null
  ],
  "key2": [
    10,
    null,
    null
  ],
  "key3": [
    null,
    null,
    2
  ]
}
```